# Rails 5 Form Select Tag not Showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, materialize

I'm creating a Blog app with RoR using MaterializeCss for my Styling, already created this:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  validates :title, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5 }
  validates :body, presence: true
end
```

Also this:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :posts
    validates :name, presence: true, length: { minimum: 3 }
end
```

Also added the migration:

```
class AddCategoryToPost < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_reference :posts, :category, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

**Update:** I have this form_for:

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
    <ul class="collection with-header">
      <li class="collection-header"><h5><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prevented this post from saving</h5></li>
      <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li class="collection-item"><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
  <div class="input-field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title%>
  </div>

  <div class="input-field">
    <%= f.label :body %><br><br>
    <%= f.hidden_field :body, class: "materialize-textarea", id: :post_body %>
    <trix-editor input="post_body"></trix-editor>
  </div>

  <div class="input-field">
    <%= f.label :category_id %>
    <%= f.collection_select(:category_id, Category.all, :id, :name) %>
  </div>
  <br> <br> <br> <br>
  <div class="right">
   <%= f.submit "Save Post", class: "waves-effect waves-light btn" %>
  </div>  
<% end %>
```

And as you can see I'm trying to list all my Categories from Category Model, but in my browser I have this result:
[image: Browser View Render the Select with all the Categories]

As you can see, **it render all the Categories(javascript, ruby on rails, angularjs, PHP)** but **I can't see the Select in my New Post Form and Can't click on the Select**,

any clue?

**Update: Removed Materializecss classes, and Still Not Showing the Select Input**
[image: Removed MaterializeCss Styles]

Comment: Can you show more code from the view? (at least including the form_for). The other input fields are shown? By the way (this is not the problem, but) why does category belongs_to user?

Comment: Hi @Pablo, in my case, users also can create Categories, so in that way they can Edit or Delete only their own Categories

Comment: OK. In the view you are showing all categories (even categories from other users). The other fields in the form are shown correctly? Can it be something wrong in trix or in your css formating? Have you tried removing the other fields just to test only this one?

Comment: Yes @Pablo already tried that, other fields work great, also removed trix and nothing happen... Is wear, because it render the select, but not showing, I will try with another CSS Framework

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem too. What I did id just in my Css I added

```
select{
 display: block;
}
```

And that fixed the issue

Answer (score -1):

Found the problem, it's MaterializeCss that is Not showing me the Select Input, and I don't now Why?. Going back to my old friend Bootstrap